# Lucee form field is not passing correctly

Tags: forms, lucee

In Lucee..  Using a form with the post method and inside it I have:

```
 <table>  
 ...stuff
    <cfloop array = "#selrarr#" index = "xxcol">      

      <td>
         <input type    = "text"                 
                name    = "selr"  
                id      = "selrfrom#xxcol#" <!---xxcol is index in a loop--->
                style   = "width:100%"
                value   = ""
                onclick = "tipshow('tip_range', '#selrmsg#')"> <!---selrmsg included earlier--->      
       </td> 
       <td> param
          <input type = "text"
              name    = "selr" 
              id      = "selrto#xxcol#" 
              style   = "width:100%"  
              value   = ""
              onclick = "tipshow('tip_range', '#selrmsg#')">        
       </td> 
 </cfloop>
```

Both values are empty.  However when I pass them to the next program one of them is coming out not empty:

```
  <cfset rangearr  = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('selr')>
  <cfdump var = "#rangearr#" label = 'let3init 38 rangearr'>
```

[image]

How can this happen?  It is messing up later code where I test whether the value is empty.  Has anyone seen this kind of thing?  Any clue about what might cause it?

Comment: I've just tried your code and I get all empty strings. Also, all your fields have the same name, so will be passed altogether if you do that, if they have values, as a comma-delimited list. Plus, you don't need the getPageContext... stuff, you can just use the form scope, e.g. #form.selr#

Comment: I'm glad you got all empty strings.  Obviously I did not.  Re the getPaqeContext there is good reason to use it.  The comma delimited list passed by the form omits null values -- and yet that is exactly what I want to pick up here.  getPageContext also kindly returns and array which is safer to deal with.

Comment: Which version of Lucee is this from?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have no idea what version I have.  However, I did locate the problem, which was a javascript program running before I attempted to pick up the information.  Thanks for helping.